# Getting really poor performance on MySQL query

Tags: mysql, database-performance

I have a query with sub-query that should be lightning fast, and instead it's unusably slow.  Can anyone suggest ways to get MySQL to perform properly?

Using MySQL Server version: 5.5.41 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Doing a combined query:

```
Explain SELECT * FROM StudySpecSubject WHERE SubjectID IN (
                 SELECT SubjectID FROM StudySpecSubject WHERE SpecimenID ='123456');

 id select_type         table            type       possible_keys   key     key_len ref        rows     Extra                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
--- ------------------- ---------------- ---------- --------------- ------- ------- ---------- -------- ------------------------
  1 PRIMARY             StudySpecSubject ALL        <null>          <null>  <null>  <null>     14015412 Using where             
  2 DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  StudySpecSubject index_subq Subject,rlimsID Subject 66      func,const 1        Using index; Using where
```

Doing the exact same query as two separate queries:

```
Explain SELECT SubjectID FROM StudySpecSubject WHERE SpecimenID ='123456';
Explain SELECT * FROM StudySpecSubject WHERE SubjectID IN ('AB-CDEF');

 id select_type         table            type possible_keys key     key_len ref   rows Extra
--- ------------------- ---------------- ---- ------------- ------- ------- ----- ---- -----------
  1 SIMPLE              StudySpecSubject ref  rlimsID       rlimsID 33      const 1    Using where

 id select_type         table            type possible_keys key     key_len ref   rows Extra
--- ------------------- ---------------- ---- ------------- ------- ------- ----- ---- -----------
  1 SIMPLE              StudySpecSubject ref  Subject       Subject 33      const 52   Using where
```

Table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE `StudySpecSubject` (
    StudyID VarChar(31) NOT NULL, 
    SubjectID VarChar(31) NOT NULL, 
    SpecimenID VarChar(31) NOT NULL, 
    which Int unsigned NOT NULL, 
    INDEX Study (StudyID, SubjectID, SpecimenID), 
    INDEX Subject (SubjectID, SpecimenID), 
    INDEX rlimsID (SpecimenID), 
    INDEX byTable (which)
) ENGINE = INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: I could be incorrect, but is this different than `SELECT * FROM StudySpecSubject WHERE SpecimanID = '123456';` ?

Comment: @Ben It's a little different. A `SubjectID` can have multiple rows in the table. This query gets all the rows for every `SubjectID` if one of their rows has `SpecimentID = '123456`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL is notoriously bad at some `WHERE IN (SELECT ...)` queries. It's better to write them as `JOIN`.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM StudySpecSubject AS t1
JOIN StudySpecSubject AS t2 ON t1.SubjectID = t2.SubjectID
WHERE t2.SpecimenID = '123456'
```

The MySQL bug is that instead of getting all the subject IDs from the subquery, and using that to index the table, it scans the entire table in the main query and then performs the subquery to test if the subject ID is in the returned table.